# Oveloaded function static method error

Tags: c#, overloading

I was going through an example which is below

```
class Program
{
    public static void Show(String pstrMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pstrMessage);
    }
    public void Show(Object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program=new Program();
        program.Show("Test Message");
    }
}
```

When I remove the static function it is working fine.
 Other wise it is giving me a compile time error.
can't access Static method "show" in non static context.
As I think object is the base class for all then it should automatically typecasted to object (implicit typcasting). 
Can anyone explain why it is giving an error.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason for `Show(Object)` to be a non-static member function. Declare that function `static` too.

Then, you'll need to use `Program.Show` (with the class name) instead of `program.Show` (with the instance name) because you're calling a static function.

Comment: Yes you are right but I want to know why it is giving me the compilation error. "the show method (object)" should be static is the region?

Comment: You are getting an error because C# requires that you use the name of the *class* (not an instance) when referring to a static member.

Comment: When you remove the static method, you are no longer trying to call a static method!

Comment: But I am not specifying that I want to call static method. Since I am calling the method with an instance? What is the conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

When multiple method names match, the compiler runs an *overload resolution procedure* to decide which method is more specific. In your case, the static overload happens to be the *most specific one*, because it takes a `string` rather than `object`. The compiler complains that you should be calling it using `Program.Show("Test Message");`

Comment: Do you mean that compiler is not smart about calling a static or non static method? Or it look for overloaded first and then static and non static

Comment: @krshekhar Compiler's job is to do what you say, not to do what it thinks that you want. It wouldn't be smart of the compiler to guess your intentions, and silently call the static method, even though your code explicitly says that you want an instance method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the instance function, just using program.Show((Object)"Test Message");

Comment: this is a way to call the function. I want to know why not above is working.

Comment: After build, every function has its address. you want to call the function Show(string), so cannot access the function with a instance pointer. Not familiar with c#, but in c++. Below code works well.class MyClass
{
public:
 void print()
 {
  cout<<"print";
 }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 MyClass *pMyClass = NULL;
 pMyClass->print();
}